# How to extract the first column from an output line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parsing, command

When executing

```
sudo fdisk -l | tail -n 1
```

the result gives me

```
/dev/sdb1   *        8064     7669823     3830880    b  W95 FAT32
```

So what I need is to extract just "/dev/sdb1/".
Not exactly just sdb1, whatever device that is listed last. What if I have two flash drives and I need the last one?

I've searching everywhere and I couldn't find how.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo fdisk -l | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

will produce  as

```
/dev/sdb1
```